# Root of IK arm is twisting

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

[image: Underside view]

The root of my IK arms are twisting, this is because I need to either roll the bones or apply a pole angle in order to make the elbow fold in the correct direction, unparenting and removing the armature and then reparenting is not helping, what can I do to fix this?

Comment: So, as you say, have you tried to change the Pole Angle? If it doesn't work, please share your file

Comment: @moonboots Adding the pole angle makes the elbow point towards the correct direction but twists the mesh https://workupload.com/file/uKGSjv6tp4c

Comment: you need to set a Pole Angle of about 70° for your forearm.R and the shoulder won't deform anymore. Also it would be better to align the bones with the axis, select them in Edit mode and Shift N

Comment: @moonboots  Yeah but then the elbow points in the wrong direction, that's why the bones are rolled like that in the first place

Comment: If I choose a 70° pole angle I don't see the elbow pointing bad, it points exactly like it does if I deactivate the Armature modifier

Comment: First thing realign the bones in Edit mode (Shift N), then correct the pole angle of your IK and it works

Comment: @moonboots Here's what happens when I set a 70° angle: https://imgur.com/a/shAwQjL

EDIT: I'm trying the thing you commented at the same time as me now

EDIT2: Same result, whatever I do the mesh is always twisted when the elbow is pointing backwards

Comment: Flatten the arm and forearm on Z, Shift N to align with the axis, Ctrl R to make them have the same orientation, bend a bit the elbow background, align the Pole Target with the elbow on Z, change the Pole Angle of the IK and it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Edit* mode, flatten the arm and forearm on Z (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>), <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to align with the axis, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to make them have the same orientation, bend a bit the elbow background, align the *Pole Target* with the elbow on Z, in the IK modifier change the *Pole Angle* of the IK and it works fine (also put the *Armature* modifier above the *Subdivision Surface*):

Front view:

[image]

Top view:

[image]

Comment: Won't the misalignment of the bones now cause problems with the way the mesh deforms during movement?

Comment: If your talking about the elbow that needs to be bent a bit, as seen in the second image (top view), it's necessary to indicate in what direction the arm is supposed to bend